# concat two columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four columns on data gridview and want them to concat  in sql and exporting it to txt file but everytime i export this is my result.

My result

```
0010000 01500 00000 0001600
```

output required

```
001000001500000000001600
```

SQL Query:

```
 string stringSql = " SELECT distinct  " +
     "REPLACE(RIGHT('00'+CAST(CAST(bat.PCN_Charge* 100.00 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),8) as CLAIMAMT, + RIGHT('0'+CAST(CAST([CFee] * 100 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),5),' ','' )as CFEE," +
      "REPLACE(RIGHT('00000'+CAST(CAST([Solictors Fees]  AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),5), + RIGHT('000'+CAST(CAST(bat.PCN_Charge + [CFee]*100 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),9),' ','') as TotalAMT " +
```

Comment: Which SQL engine are you using?

Comment: SQL server mangment studio

Comment: Tried that still the same

Comment: _Why_ are you trying to do this?  Normally you'd just get the separate columns, **especially** for something like amounts.  And why are you multiplying a monetary amount by a float?  That runs the risk of running afoul of the decimal imprecisions inherent in the format.  Otherwise, you may have better luck formatting this in your application-layer.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the manual:

Method 1: Concatenating two strings

```
SELECT 'FirstName' + ' ' + 'LastName' AS FullName
```

Method 2: Concatenating two Numbers

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(2 AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Method 3: Concatenating values of table columns

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName
FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Contact
```

In your case, you should do the same, avoiding the space in between.

Comment: I see a REPLACE in your example, not a CAST

Comment: @preethi Why do you separate the fields with commas??

Answer (score 0):

```
select first_column+' '+second_c+' '+third_c+' '+forth_c
from table_name
```

Comment: error if i try this...Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '+'.
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'ta'.  
  `"REPLACE(RIGHT('00'+CAST(CAST(bat.PCN_Charge* 100.00 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),8) as CLAIMAMT+' '+ RIGHT('0'+CAST(CAST([CFee] * 100 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),5),' ','' )as CFEE," +`

Comment: Additionally it should be noted that if any of these columns have a NULL value, the whole row will be NULL using the + method of concatenation. If your columns can have null values, you should consider using isnull(columnName, '') for each nullable column.

Comment: I must be missing something. Wasn't the op intention **not** to have the spaces?

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
declare @result varchar(500)
set @result = ''
select @result = @result +' '+first_c+' '+second_c+' '+third_c+' '+forth_c
from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @a varchar(50) 
set @a='0010000 01500 00000 0001600'
select replace(@a,' ','')
```

## [SEE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15381)

Comment: It'd probably be preferable to avoid creating the spaces in the first place.